# render multiple template from a single view in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I want to send context data to one html and want to render different html.
After login user is redirected to this dashboard view. Here I want to render two html file, the context value will be sent to one html let say temp1.html file, but user can see temp2.html file. In temp2.html and other html file, I will include temp1.html file. Is there any way to do so?
views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    print('in dashboard view')
    object = UserSelection.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if object.user_type == 'candidate':
        val_cand = CandidateDetail.objects.filter(candidate_username=request.user)
        if val_cand:
            print('Candidate filled data') #Already filled data
            data = CandidateDetail.objects.get(candidate_username=request.user)
            return render(request, 'dashboard.html',{'obj':object.user_type, 'data':data})
        else:
            print('new user') #Registered but not filled data
            return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'obj':object.user_type})

    else:
        val_emp = EmployerDetail.objects.filter(name=request.user)
        if val_emp:
            print('Employer filled data') #Already filled data
            data = EmployerDetail.objects.get(name=request.user)
            return render(request, 'dashboard.html',{'obj':object.user_type, 'data':data})
        else:
            print('new user') #Registered but not filled data
            return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'obj':object.user_type})
```

Comment: Can you explain how you display two html file in one html ?

Comment: I am sending context data to temp1.html file, based on some condition there will be some value. I have many html files in my project, there I will include temp1.html file using {% include 'file_name' %} tag. @Raja Simon

Comment: If `parent` html file can access the `variable` send by view function then `child` html file also able to access it. Is that what you want.? Or Do you want to pass additional varaibles to child html ?

Comment: yes but in the same view, I want user to be redirected to temp2.html file and only data will be sent to temp1.html file.                                         def dash(request):
    val_cand = 
    CandidateDetail.objects.get(candidate_username=request.user)
    return render(request, 'temp2.html')
    return render(request, 'temp1.html', {'value':val_cand})                           
    I want something like this @Raja Simon

Comment: What you mean by redirected? It's so confusing and this question may be close because of `Unclear what you are asking` Please edit your question with more info...

Comment: Also why you want to render two html file ?

Comment: In my project, after user logs in, he should see temp2.html file. and inside temp2.html and many other html file, temp1.html file will be included.@Raja Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't render two html file in single view. Please use the Django template language for the desired behaivour.

i.e) If your passing `obj` to `dashboard.html` and inside html files can also access obj.

*dashboard.html*

```
{{ obj }}

{% include 'test1.html' %}
{% include 'test2.html' %}
```

You can pass additional context to the template using keyword arguments:

```
{% include 'test1.html' with obj=obj additional_context='blah' %}
```

*test1.html*

```
{{ obj }}
```