# django generic view send context to multiple templates at the same time

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I am trying to send the listview context (book_list) in this case to more than one template at the same time.

I have tried to edit templates_names by doing this:

```
class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    def get_template_names(self):
        template_name=["catalog/index.html","catalog/book_list.html"]
        return template_name
```

but book_list is still only known to catalog/book_list.html not to catalog/index.html(so the function I have added did NOT do anything).

any suggestions please?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot :) Each view is responsible for one url and one template in will render. Actually I cannot even find and example when one would need to do what you're trying to do.

I think you have to read about [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

Comment: thanks for replying...I thought so ,but I have been trying to find away around it. thanks for confirming it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

[render multiple template from a single view in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913432/render-multiple-template-from-a-single-view-in-django)

I had same problem. If you send arguments to parents html and if your htmls are children. They can access to arguments. check the link.