# More than one template render from one view in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, view, render

I have a view that has some raw queries and I need to use these queries on more than one html page (template). How can I render the context of the view to two templates?
-- I know it is better to use generic view to this view but it's not important now. --

**views.py**

```
def results(request,user_name_id):

    # VEZETŐI TESZT
    vezetoi_hatekonysag = Vezetoi.objects.raw(...)
    vezetoi_iranyito = Vezetoi.objects.raw(...)
    vezetoi_motivalo = Vezetoi.objects.raw(...)
    vezetoi_tamogato = Vezetoi.objects.raw(...)
    vezetoi_delegalo = Vezetoi.objects.raw(...)

    # VISELKEDÉSTÍPUS TESZT
    viselkedes_iranyito = Vezetoi.objects.raw(...)
    viselkedes_inspiralo = Vezetoi.objects.raw(...)
    viselkedes_tamogato = Vezetoi.objects.raw('...)
    viselkedes_elemzo = Vezetoi.objects.raw(...)


context = {
    # VEZETŐIKOMPETENCIA ÉS HATÉKNYSÁG
    'vezetoi_hatekonysag': vezetoi_hatekonysag,
    'vezetoi_iranyito': vezetoi_iranyito,
    'vezetoi_motivalo': vezetoi_motivalo,
    'vezetoi_tamogato': vezetoi_tamogato,
    'vezetoi_delegalo': vezetoi_delegalo,

    # VISELKEDÉSTÍPUS
    'viselkedes_iranyito': viselkedes_iranyito,
    'viselkedes_inspiralo': viselkedes_inspiralo,
    'viselkedes_tamogato': viselkedes_tamogato,
    'viselkedes_elemzo': viselkedes_elemzo,
}

return render(request, 'stressz/all_user.html', context)
```

Comment: you can find the answer here [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913432/render-multiple-template-from-a-single-view-in-django)

Comment: you could also use context_processors, that would allow you to use that query on all your templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One view can only return only one response(one page) and it cannot use multiple html template.

If you want to use different templates for different queries(determine the template dynamically). :

```
def your_view(request, user_name_id):
  # ...do queries...
  if SOME_LOGIC: 
    template_name = 'path/to/template1.html'
  else: 
    template_name = 'path/to/template2.html'
  return render(request, template_name, context)
```

And if you need only a part of content to be different in a template, one option is to add the template to `context` and include it in html file like `context['my_list'] = 'path/to/girl_list.html'` or `context['my_list'] = path/to/boy_list.html`

template.html:

```html
{% block someblock %}
...
  {% include my_list %}
...
{% endlbock %}
```