# how to return multiple file html in render request django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I would like to return multiple values in multiple html files in a django view
i tried that but it was a mistake

```
def my_view(request):
#bla bla bla...
context ={
   'value_1':value,
    #....
}
return  render(request,{'file_1.html','file_2.html','file_2.html'},context)
```

I have already separated it into 3 different views but the problem is that they have the same source and if I separate them I had 4 min of execution time, then the best is to combine them

Comment: Only one file can be used at a time per render. Maybe combine those into one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913432/render-multiple-template-from-a-single-view-in-django

Comment: you can just import views.py folder in projects urls.py and add path as path('', views.index, name='index'), and call html pages by url than rendering

Comment: How do we do that? I've never tried

Answer (score 0):

**urls.py**

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.values2, name='values1'),
    path('value2/', views.values2, name='values2'),
]
```

from here you can call all html pages without giving load to server

Comment: i did this in my view, but i don't think that's what i want but what i want is to return a lot of variable about 10 in different html file

Comment: 'value_1':value, 'value_2':value, in htm1: value1 will be called, in htm2: value2 will be called  is it like

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just simply using in built functionality.

```
def my_view(request):
...
context ={
   'template1_context':value1,
   'template2_context':value2,
   'template3_context':value3,
}
return  render(request,'main_template.html',context)
```

And in your `main_template.html`

```
{% include "template2.html" with template2_variable=template2_context %}
{% include "template3.html" with template3_variable=template3_context %}
```

Comment: yes that's kind of what I want, export the values in another template in order to minimize the execution time
the problem with your code is that it includes all the content of template2.html in main_template.html when we only want the values

Comment: It's not possible to render multiple html templates at a time with django `render`. So either you render only one html template with separate values or use one html and fill your value2 and value3 using calling different views using AJAX requests.